# MySQL vertices & edges intersection

Tags: mysql, database, graph, union

I have 2 tables: `edges` and `users`

`edges` (with constraint: id1 < id2):

```
id1
name1
id2
name2
```

`users`:

```
id
name
```

I'd like to get a result set of only edges (id1, name1, id2, name2) such that BOTH id1 and id2 are in the users table. This seems pretty simple, but I'm having trouble getting it. My attempt:

```
SELECT
   e.id1 AS id1,
   e.name1 AS name1,
   e.id2 AS id2,
   e.name2 AS name2
FROM 
   edges AS e,
   users AS u
WHERE u.id = e.id1

UNION

SELECT
   e.id1 AS id1,
   e.name1 AS name1,
   e.id2 AS id2,
   e.name2 AS name2
FROM 
   edges AS e,
   users AS u
WHERE u.id = e.id2
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using two INNER JOINS like this:

```
SELECT * FROM edges e 
JOIN users u1 ON e.name1 = u1.name 
JOIN users u2 ON e.name2 = u2.name
```

Comment: This works! It is a bit slow, but I suppose the first JOIN is a `O(|V| * |E|)` operation, so these joins together would make a runtime of `O(|V| * |E|^2)`? Probably the best we can do here?

Comment: Create an index on the three name fields to improve performance.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that if your users table is smaller than edges table you can do first a RIGHT JOIN and then a LEFT JOIN and it will speed up the query.

Comment: So in that case, we have a hashing from each of those fields to another, meaning that we have `O(1) * O(|V|)` for the first join lookups and then add another `O(|V|)` for the second one, meaning a total of `O(|V|)`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
select e.id1, e.name1, e.id2, e.name2 from edges e
join users u1 on e.id1 = u1.id
join users u2 on e.id2 = u2.id
```

Comment: yes this is @jordeu's but here you get rid of the duplicate columns, which is what is desired. any thoughts on the runtime as I wondered above?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
   e.id1 AS id1,
   e.name1 AS name1,
   e.id2 AS id2,
   e.name2 AS name2
FROM 
   edges AS e
WHERE EXISTS
  (
      SELECT
        NULL
      FROM
        users AS u
      WHERE
        u.id = e.id1
        AND u.id = e.id2
  )
```

Comment: hmm this returns the empty set?

Comment: No. It returns the eges that has users.